# Populate by code SelectOneMenu based on custom meta-data in attributes

Tags: jsf, dynamic, populate, selectonemenu

I need a solution to populate by code SelectOneMenu using some meta-data specified as an attribute to this component.

Here is the detail of my requirement.

1) The developer would specify some thing like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="someComponent" value="#{someController.someModel.someField}">
    <f:attribute name="entity" value="somepackage.SomeEntity" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

2) When the page containing the above is requested for the first time, the server should be able to read the 'entity' attribute

3) Once the 'entity' is read, the server will do the needful to populate dynamically 'someComponent'.

I have no issue with the code that should use the 'entity' attribute and generate the content to be show in 'someComponent'. My issue is to found the appropriate place to call efficiently this code.

I have tried the PhaseEventListener for 'After Render Response Phase' but with no luck. It looks like I'm missing something fundamental as I'm new to JSF.

Have someone went through the same experiment?

Thank you in advance.

Younes Ouadi

Comment: Do you target a Servlet 3.0/EL 2.2 container?

Comment: My development environment is Tomcat 7, so it is as you say. However, I would prefer, in case it is possible, a solution that is also valid for a container with Servlet 2.5 and EL 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you target an EL 2.2 container which supports invoking methods with arguments and/or supply [JBoss EL](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) with your webapp so that it works on EL 2.1 as well, then it should be possible with the following construct:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="someComponent" value="#{someController.someModel.someField}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{someProvider.selectItems('somepackage.SomeEntity')}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
public List<SelectItem> getSelectItems(String className) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd introduce some lazy loading and/or request-based caching mechanism as well as a getter can be called more than once during bean's life.

Comment: I see your solution. But, it is oriented more toward developers than page authors. I would prefer using meta-data (through <f:attribute />). Never-mind, many thanks for your prompt responses.